# Generate a self working EXP system for levels

Tags: c#

I am making a small game in C# and I can't figure out how to make a self working EXP system that gets the EXP you need to level up by the players current level.

This is how I want it to work.

```
1 = 75
2 = 75 + 75 = 150
3 = 75 + 75 + 75 + 75 = 300
4 = 75 + 75 + 75 + 75 + 75 + 75 + 75 = 525
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I'm guessing `75 * (1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4) = 825`

Comment: yes 825 would be at level 5

Comment: @MichaelGuercia: In that case, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your pattern is "add one 75, add two 75s, add three 75s"... This could be written mathematically as:

```
s_1 = 75
s_{n+1} = s_n + 75 * n
```

This means that you can use use

```
(1 + level * (level - 1) / 2) * 75
```

Comment: check #4... it's only there 7 times, not 8

Answer (score 0):

Some simple math, assuming you want exponential grow? Psuedocode: `requiredExp = 75 * Math.pow(2, level - 1)`

If you're using arbitrary numbers, you could use a dictionary. Map level to experience.

Edit: Adding one more 75 each time (sum of arithmetic sequence). `requiredExp = 75 * (1 + (level - 1) * level / 2)` should do

Comment: @DavidRobinson nice deduction

Comment: Okay, updating answer. You can see I don't do much beyond simple math :P

Comment: The problem is that we don't have enough data to make a pattern...we need more of his expected levels.  Regardless

Comment: That doesn't quite work (on level 4 it gives 675, for instance)

Comment: Yeah ugh, I wrote a sample function but I should have just copy pasted instead of trying to remembering it. Upvoted yours, you got the function right first :P

Comment: the pattern is:
the previous level's exp + (75 * the previous level)